# Things to check after dropping a Nexus 7

Tags: nexus-7

I just dropped my Nexus 7 from about a height of 4 feet. It landed on a hard floor, but luckily there were no cracks. But, when I picked it up, it.....rebooted....?

I've read sites telling me that the hardware inside tends to break before the screen, so what should I check to see what, if anything, is broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tablet probably rebooted because the impact caused the battery to go loose for a split second.

I would check all the sensors with an app like [CPU-Z](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z), making sure that all the sensors respond to any change. That should cover most of the potential damage.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I ran a performance benchmark test, and nothing seemed to be wrong. Will try CPU-Z. I was curious as to why it restarted though.